# iOS Dark Keyboard has background during UINavigationController push/pop animation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikeyboard

During the navigation controller push/pop animation, keyboard is darker then it is in its final state. And on animation end, this black background view just disappears. Light (white) keyboard style does not have this effect.

How can I get rid of this black background?

I already tried setting the window color to white and setting the navigation controller background to white.

**VIDEO:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1grj821fj306th/Untitled.mov?dl=0

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer/solution?

Comment: Nope, I stopped chasing this, it was not on client's priority list and we moved in another direction. Too bad keyboard on iOS is having its own consciousness, e.g. sometimes it stays visible during side-swipe-to-dismiss and sometimes it hides interactively when you are sliding VC from right to left to dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

The easiest solution is to just to disable the keyboard transparency by setting its background color to black or white (depending on if you have a light or dark keyboard):

```
myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

guard UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone else {
    return;
}

//keyboard window should be there now, look for it:
var keyboardWindow: UIWindow?
for window in UIApplication.shared.windows.reversed() {
    if String(describing: type(of: window)) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow" {
        keyboardWindow = window
        break
    }
}
keyboardWindow?.rootViewController?.view.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = .black
```

**Option 2**

If you don't like this I have a hack that seems to work pretty well, at least in iOS 14. It results in the keyboard slide up animation occurring during the slide in push animation, instead of after. It relies on showing the keyboard right before pushing by adding a temporary text field.

Run this code whenever you want to push the VC:

```
guard UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone else {
    // fix doesn't apply to iPad, push or perform segue:
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    // navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    return;
}

//create text field with matching settings so keyboard will look the same as its destination
let tempTextField = UITextField.init()
tempTextField.keyboardType = .default
tempTextField.keyboardAppearance = .light
tempTextField.autocorrectionType = .default
view.addSubview(tempTextField)
    
//show keyboard, then right after push VC, then discard the text field
//make sure destination text field calls becomeFirstResponder() in its VC's viewDidLoad()
tempTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0/60.0) {
    // push or perform segue:
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    // navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        tempTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

**Option 3**

I improved on option 2 by copying the push slide animation to the keyboard, essentially resulting in exactly what you asked. There is also the option to keep the sliding up animation too during the slide in, just give it a try.

Run this code on the pushing VC whenever you want to push:

```
guard UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone else {
    // fix doesn't apply to iPad, push or perform segue:
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    // navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    return;
}

//create text field with matching settings so keyboard will look the same as its destination
let tempTextField = UITextField.init()
tempTextField.keyboardType = .default
tempTextField.keyboardAppearance = .light
tempTextField.autocorrectionType = .default
view.addSubview(tempTextField)
       
//show keyboard, then push VC, then remove the text field (see bottom)
//make sure destination text field calls becomeFirstResponder() in its VC's viewDidLoad()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) //set to false to disable slide up animation or true to keep it
tempTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

//find keyboard window
var keyboardWindow: UIWindow?
for window in UIApplication.shared.windows.reversed() {
    if String(describing: type(of: window)) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow" {
        keyboardWindow = window
        break
    }
}
keyboardWindow?.rootViewController?.view.isHidden = true //this prevents glitches

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0/60.0) {
    // push or perform segue
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
    // navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    
    keyboardWindow?.rootViewController?.view.isHidden = false

    //this spring animation is identical to default push slide animation
    let spring = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    spring.damping = 500
    spring.mass = 3
    spring.initialVelocity = 0
    spring.stiffness = 1000
    spring.fromValue = CGPoint.init(x: self.view.frame.width, y:0) //you can enter e.g y:1000 to delay slide up animation
    spring.toValue = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y:0)
    spring.duration = 0.5
    spring.isAdditive = true
    keyboardWindow?.layer.add(spring, forKey: nil)
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    tempTextField.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

You can keep the sliding up animation by not disabling the animations (above becomeFirstResponder()). If you choose this it is possible to delay the slide up animation by replacing y:0 with y:1000 for example. You can play with this value.